# How to test result of UnityWebRequest?

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, httprequest

I'm trying to make a prototype of a game in Unity. I have a MySQL DB and I can register a user in it.

So what I have trouble with is getting an error message whenever I fill the fields wrong. Like the two fields with password that need to match before sending the SQL request and then loading a new scene.

I have tried with `if(www.downloadHandler.text == "")` but if I don't fill the field of infos, my test passes because it return an `""`

This is my c# file:

```
IEnumerator Insertion()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("Identifiant", IdField.text);
    form.AddField("MotPasse", MdpField.text);
    form.AddField("MotPasseConfi", MdpConfirField.text);
    form.AddField("Email", EmailField.text);
    form.AddField("NoTel", NoTelField.text);

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost/AppAndroid/inscription.php", form);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();


    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        // It doesn't works, show error message
        Debug.Log(www.error);
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
    else
    {
        // It works, load new scene
        Debug.Log("c'est passé !");
        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

and this is my php file:

```
<?php
$SRVusername="root";
$SRVpassword="";
$SRVadress="localhost";
$SRVdatabase="envapp";

$connexion=mysqli_connect($SRVadress,$SRVusername,$SRVpassword,$SRVdatabase);

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "1: Erreur de connexion";
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST["Identifiant"]) && isset($_POST["MotPasse"]) && isset($_POST["Email"]) && isset($_POST["NoTel"]) && isset($_POST["MotPasseConfi"]))
{
    $Identifiant = $_POST["Identifiant"];
    $MotPasse = $_POST["MotPasse"];
    $Email = $_POST["Email"];
    $NoTel = $_POST["NoTel"];
    $MotPasseConfi = $_POST["MotPasseConfi"];

    if($MotPasse == $MotPasseConfi)
    {
            $checkquery = "INSERT INTO `joueurs` (`ID_JOUEUR`, `PSEUDO`, `PASSWORD`, `EMAIL`, `NUMTEL`) VALUES (NULL, '".$Identifiant."', '".$MotPasse."', '".$Email."', '".$NoTel."');";

            $checkstate = mysqli_query($connexion,$checkquery) or die("4: Erreur lors de la requête " .$checkquery);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "3: Erreur Les mots de passe ne correspondent pas !";
        exit();
    }
}
else
{
    echo "2: Erreur Les POST ne sont pas passés !";
    exit();
}
mysqli_close($connexion);
?>
```

Comment: could you please add the code you use when it fails .. including the check and exactly how you test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest rather using e.g. [`http_response_code`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) to set a proper http response code (like `500` - see [list of http response codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)) and rather use these for testing:

```
<?php
$SRVusername="root";
$SRVpassword="";
$SRVadress="localhost";
$SRVdatabase="envapp";

$connexion=mysqli_connect($SRVadress,$SRVusername,$SRVpassword,$SRVdatabase);

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    printf("1: Erreur de connexion\n");
    http_response_code(500);
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST["Identifiant"]) && isset($_POST["MotPasse"]) && isset($_POST["Email"]) && isset($_POST["NoTel"]) && isset($_POST["MotPasseConfi"]))
{
    $Identifiant = $_POST["Identifiant"];
    $MotPasse = $_POST["MotPasse"];
    $Email = $_POST["Email"];
    $NoTel = $_POST["NoTel"];
    $MotPasseConfi = $_POST["MotPasseConfi"];

    if($MotPasse == $MotPasseConfi)
    {
            $checkquery = "INSERT INTO `joueurs` (`ID_JOUEUR`, `PSEUDO`, `PASSWORD`, `EMAIL`, `NUMTEL`) VALUES (NULL, '".$Identifiant."', '".$MotPasse."', '".$Email."', '".$NoTel."');";

            if($checkstate = mysqli_query($connexion,$checkquery))
            {
                http_response_code(200);
            } else {
                printf("4: Erreur lors de la requête %s\n", $checkquery);
                http_response_code(500);
                exit();
            }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("3: Erreur Les mots de passe ne correspondent pas !");
        http_response_code(500);
        exit();
    }
}
else
{
    printf("2: Erreur Les POST ne sont pas passés !");
    http_response_code(500);
    exit();
}
mysqli_close($connexion);
?>
```

Then you can fully rely on the

```
if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
{
    // It doesn't works, show error message
    Debug.Log(www.error);
    Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
}
```

or simply check the response code like

```
if(www.responseCode != 200) { ... }
```

---

alternatively for custom response texts you can also use header like e.g.

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]. ' ' . 500 . ' ' . "1: Erreur de connexion");
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for...I was sure I was returning no Http error. Thank you man.

Answer (score 1):

I do no know how you would respond in PHP but my answer would be that you return a relevant error code (perhaps [412 - Precondition Failed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/412) in your case). This would allow you to check the `.isHttpError` property of the `UnityWebRequest`; see [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-isHttpError.html).

The client can either interpret the response code and display an error (in the right language) or you could add a header to the reponse with details. The latter could be accessed by the `.GetResponseHeader` [property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.GetResponseHeader.html).

However, I would suggest you validate what you can on the Unity client before sending a request. Simple validation of the passwords matching can be checked easily and will avoid you sending a request you know is going to fail.